# How to bypassing the Cloudflare captcha?

Tags: python, proxy, cloudflare

Trying to bypass Cloudflare's wall, I wanted to get access to cf_clearence...

I tried **cfscrape**, link to the package [[link]](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/blob/master/README.md).

```
import cfscrape

cookie_value, user_agent = cfscrape.get_cookie_string("https://somesite.com")
request += "Cookie: %s\r\nUser-Agent: %s\r\n" % (cookie_value, user_agent)

print(request)
```

This should return *cf_clearance*, and *__cfduid*, but in our case its returning,
`requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://somesite.com`

Also tried **cf_clearance**, to make a Cloudflare challenge pass successfully, the code that I tried:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from cf_clearance import sync_cf_retry, sync_stealth
import requests

# not use cf_clearance, cf challenge is fail
proxies = {
    "all": "socks5://localhost:7890"
}
res = requests.get('https://somesite.com', proxies=proxies)
if '<title>Please Wait... | Cloudflare</title>' in res.text:
    print("cf challenge fail")
# get cf_clearance
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False, proxy={"server": "socks5://localhost:7890"})
    page = browser.new_page()
    sync_stealth(page, pure=True)
    page.goto('https://somesite.com')
    res = sync_cf_retry(page)
    if res:
        cookies = page.context.cookies()
        for cookie in cookies:
            if cookie.get('name') == 'cf_clearance':
                cf_clearance_value = cookie.get('value')
                print(cf_clearance_value)
        ua = page.evaluate('() => {return navigator.userAgent}')
        print(ua)
    else:
        print("cf challenge fail")
    browser.close()
# use cf_clearance, must be same IP and UA
headers = {"user-agent": ua}
cookies = {"cf_clearance": cf_clearance_value}
res = requests.get('https://somesite.com', proxies=proxies, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
if '<title>Please Wait... | Cloudflare</title>' not in res.text:
    print("cf challenge success")
```

The above code was from [here](https://github.com/vvanglro/cf_clearance#sync).

Tried it with and without proxies.

With proxies:

O/P:

```
Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Without proxies:

O/P:

```
cf challenge fail
.
.
.
NotImplementedError: Encountered recaptcha. Check whether your proxy is an elite proxy.
```